# Convert float bytes to string

Tags: javascript, floating-point, byte

I have an application were I need to transmit simple data like floats as a string to a server and back. Converting those floats into the decimal format and vice versa works but probably isn't efficient, as a float is 4 bytes long but most numbers have way more then 4 decimal places. Also the conversion of decimal digits to binary float data takes some time.

So how do I

1. Extract the bytes of a `Float32Array`
2. Convert those bytes into a string
3. Extract the bytes stored in a string
4. Convert those bytes into a `Float32Array`

Comment: Do you ***really*** need to care about the size of floats and the nanoseconds the conversion takes? You know that the transferred data e.g. gets gzipped...

Comment: I don't really have an idea how long those conversions take, but if it is as low as you said, then there is no need to optimise